# Web based console connections not working in Windows 7 posted: Jan 20, 2010 8:55 AM

Tags: windows, vmware-esx, console

For slightly complicated reasons we tend to give people console access to VMs via the webui.

This has worked fine in the past, however when the users update their client machines to Windows 7 (or Vista, I am told, although I have not tested that), then the console fails to work. On IE8, having allowed the ActiveX control, the tab causes a "Internet Explorer has stopped working" dialog. On Firefox 3.5 , once the plugin has been installed, using the console causes the browser to crash.

I've updated to the most recent VC 2.5 release, and ESX 3.5u5.

Anyone else seeing this?

Any clues how to get round it (other than using the fat client).

Nigel.

Comment: What are the date and time in the title for?

Answer (score 0):

Get the VSClient 4.0U1 - it supports Windows 7 and talks just fine to 2.5/3.5 environments ([Clicky for download link](http://downloads.vmware.com/d/info/datacenter_downloads/vmware_vsphere_4/4#product_downloads))